# Why is Qur'an 33:53 (which describes specific behaviors in relation to the Prophet) inside the Qur'an?

Tags: quran, tafseer, prophet-muhammad, behavior, surat-al-ahzab

A friend of my whom I try to convert to Islam is reading the Qur'an and read this verse:

> 'O you who have believed, do not enter the houses of the Prophet except when you are permitted for a meal, without awaiting its readiness. But when you are invited, then enter; and when you have eaten, disperse without seeking to remain for conversation. Indeed, that [behavior] was troubling the Prophet, and he is shy of [dismissing] you. But Allah is not shy of the truth. And when you ask [his wives] for something, ask them from behind a partition. That is purer for your hearts and their hearts. And it is not [conceivable or lawful] for you to harm the Messenger of Allah or to marry his wives after him, ever. Indeed, that would be in the sight of Allah an enormity.' ([33:53](https://quran.com/33/53))

And asked me the question, why is this inside the Qur'an which is meant to be a gift for the whole mankind? Why is Allah dealing that much with stuff that prophet Mohammed (Peace be upon him) can deal himself also?

Aren't there more important things to say for Allah to the whole mankind?

He asked me this and I have no answer on this because also for me this verse looks like it makes no sense inside the Qur'an. So how do you explain this verse: why is it inside the holy and all-knowing Qur'an?

Comment: What your are quoting is a verse (ayah) not a surah, the qur'an actually has 114 surahs but many more verses! Secondly the qur'an is for whole mankind and we can conclude rulings from this that might apply in our daily life.

Comment: Ah thank you yes I mean verses but my englisch is not that perfect in terms of religion terminology. So that means that no widow muslim women should get married with another men after her husband dies? Or does it mean that as a guest you should leave the house of the household as quick as you eaten up? Or does it means that if you have annoying guest in your house you should not say to them that its late and time to leave but instead wait for Allah who will carry about the guests? I don't get it what we as mankind can learn from this verse, can you maybe be more specific?

Comment: Prophet Muhammad was shy to tell his guest about this. So Allah sent down the command as a verse. Once a verse has been sent down, it is part of the Qur'an and no one is allowed to change it.

Comment: Hmm but would that not mean that the all mighty everything knowing Allah made an error in his system by making our prophet to shy and so he had to intervent? And what can we muslims who are living after prophet mohammed can learn from this verse? I mean the quran is for all muslims and even for all people in the world and not just for the muslims who lived in the time of prophet mohammed or not? So I still don‘t understand why is this verse which is only related to the muslims living in the time of prophet mohammed is inside the holy quran which is for all people.

Answer (score 4):

There be at least four lessons in this verse:

1. **Etiquette for visiting**. You should be careful to not cause any inconvenience to the host, you should not enter anyone's home without their permission, if you visit then you should not loiter around but should limit the stay to what is required for your purpose.
2. **Endorsement of banquets**. Holding banquets is Sunna of the Prophet according to this verse. You should hold banquets for special occasions (like weddings), invite people to eat meals.
3. **Etiquette for interaction with the opposite sex**. You should observe hijab (or a separating partition) from them when you are going to meet them, though you can communicate with them when there is a need. Seeking knowledge from them is valid.
4. **Respect for the Prophet**. Allah has sent revelation on this minor annoyance, it demonstrates the great stature of our Prophet and the love that Allah has for him. You too should love and honor your Prophet, and make sure that your actions and speech are not discourteous towards him.

Answer (score 1):

THis verse was sent down after it had come to knowledge one of Prophet Moh(SAW) disciples was having it in mind to marry one of his wives after his demise..That was the reason Allah (SWT)commanded that verse...